# Making instances of a comp with one property varying

Tags: after-effects

So I am animating the movement of little flags on a map. Each flag is strictly the same, except for the text it bears. How can I make my flag a generic template that I can edit once and see changes in every instance, except for the text, which has to remain instance-specific ?

Thanks in advance. Greetings,
Charles.

EDIT : This seems like a hard thing to do, because one of the founding concepts of After Effects is that comp exist in one state, independently of how they are used in other comps. Changing anything that requires re-rendering of the comp changes that comp and all its uses in all other comps. (But for example one can still change the position or scale of comp A inside another comp B, or add an effect on top of comp A - blur, contrast, ... - none of these things require to re-render comp A).

Answer (score 0):

Sub-comps can't really receive instance-specific parameters, so you have to use something like encapsulation instead, where 'instances' are represented by multiple sub-comps that each reference a *common sub-comp* (i.e., the flag image).

So, in other words, you could have a comp hierarchy like this:

```
MapAndFlags comp
 ├─FlagWithText1 (comp layer)
 ├─FlagWithText2 (comp layer)
 ├─...
 ├─FlagWithTextN (comp layer)
 └─MapImage      (comp layer)
```

And within each **FlagWithText*n*** comp, you'd have, e.g.:

```
FlagWithText1 comp
 ├─Label       (text layer)
 └─JustTheFlag (comp layer)
```

Within the **JustTheFlag** comp you'd have the image of the flag which is common to all 'instances.' Any changes to this comp will be reflected throughout the rest of your project.

You can quickly create as many **FlagWithText*n*** comps as you need simply by duplicating them in the Project panel. New copies will all point to the common **JustTheFlag** comp as well as having their own 'instance' text layer.

Caveat: This approach will work as long as the text label component is not itself a sub-comp, because then all duplicates would point to a common text label, which would be bad for your purposes. In that case, check out [True Comp Duplicator](http://aescripts.com/true-comp-duplicator/) as a fancier solution to the duplication step.

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done. Since 2018, After Effects has had **master properties** to solve this exact scenario. You choose which properties in your composition that you would like to make editable and then each instance of that composition can select different values.

Search for a tutorial on master properties.